# Spritesheet JQuery background size

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate

I'm working with the animate feature within jquery in order to build a pulsating function. If I apply this to a div with a background-image sized 60px *68 px, it works perfectly fine. However, once I apply the same function to a sprite sheet (2102px * 72px), only the div scales, but the background-image doesn't seem to size correctly. Any feedback or suggestions would be greatly received.

```
    ...
    function pulse(myDiv)
    {
    $(myDiv).animate({ 
         height: something, width: something ... }
         , 500, "linear", function(){ $(myDiv).animate(
    { height: something/2, width: something/2 ... 
    }, 500, function(){ pulse(myDiv);
            }
          );
         }
       );
    }
```

I've tried adding the background-size property within the start of the query, but that doesn't seem to help at all:

```
$(myDiv).css( { "background-size": "100%" } ).animate(
{
    "background-size": "150%",
    ...
}
```

Comment: Here is a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2peLLqk3/) where I'm using [this stripe](http://i57.tinypic.com/dczhph.gif).

Comment: Thanks very much bex, your fiddle has solved my problem.